Specify a year to search for without using WHERE clause
I am trying to return total sales for each month for the year 2015. My table has data for years 2000 to 2019. When I write the query below I get the sales for every month for all years. How do I narrow it down to just 2015?
SELECT extract(year FROM ord_date) AS year
 , extract(month FROM ord_date) AS month
 , SUM(order_tot) AS Total_Sales 
FROM dsci_504.orders   
GROUP BY extract(year FROM ord_date), extract(month FROM ord_date)
ORDER BY year, month;

The first four lines of my output should look like this:



year
month
total_sales




2015
1
55527.73


2015
2
53219.29


2015
3
53661.72


2015
4
109908.03




You want to add a condition without using a WHERE condition?

add WHERE extract(year FROM ord_date) = 2015 before GROUP BY.
or you can add  HAVING extract(year FROM ord_date) = '2015' after Group by statement. WHERE statement is more effective because WHERE clause filters the rows before any aggregation or grouping happens. This means fewer rows are processed, resulting in faster performance.

Thank you. I used WHERE clause and it worked. It was my understanding that I couldn't use the WHERE clause and GROUP BY in the same query.  Obviously, that is not true.

You can always use a WHERE clause on a SELECT. In most cases, it is a mistake NOT to use one.

Technically, you could use a group by..having min(extract(year from ord_date))=2015 and get away without using a where, but that reads weird and executes worse. If dsci_504.orders was partitioned, you could also reach directly for the partition holding only the 2015 records and that would also save you the where, but that's just inconvenient since you have to look it up first, and it's doing the planner's job - it should be looking it up for you.

You could also join (values ('2015-01-01')) as f(d) on date_trunc('year',ord_date)=d. The
join..on narrows down row combinations you're pulling from tables, where filters things entering your whole query from what's left after joining, filter filters what goes into aggregates, having filters what goes out of aggregates - you can use any combination of these, all at once but you should try to filter things as early as possible, which leaves you with the where.

It has been cleared up that "without WHERE clause" was a misunderstanding. (You just cannot refer to output columns in the WHERE clause, must use input columns.)
Use proper "sargable" predicates for best performance.
And it's simpler & cheaper with a single truncated timestamp column:
SELECT date_trunc('month', ord_date) AS mon
     , sum(order_tot) AS total_sales 
FROM   dsci_504.orders
WHERE  ord_date >= '2005-01-01'  -- valid as date or timestamp constant
AND    ord_date <  '2006-01-01'
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;

ord_date can be type date or timestammp, works for either.
Even works for timestamptz: Postgres assumes the time zone of the current session. But you may want to define your time zone explicitly in that case ...
If you actually need numeric output for year and month:
SELECT extract(year FROM mon) AS year
     , extract(month FROM mon) AS month
     , total_sales 
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', ord_date) AS mon
        , sum(order_tot) AS total_sales 
   FROM   dsci_504.orders
   WHERE  ord_date >= '2005-01-01'  -- valid timestamp constant
   AND    ord_date <  '2006-01-01'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 1
   ) sub;

